# Trying to redirect to a new URL using .htaccess but some pages fail with 'two many redirects'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I moved a Magento website to a new URL and successfully redirected the entire site using the following code in my .htaccess file (using apache):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.metsuki.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, now I want to be able to redirect the old blog (which was a mini-site within the e-commerce site) that sat at in a subfolder '/blog' (e.g. www.oldsite.com/blog) to a totally different third website.

I tried amending the rule above with the following code (where thirdsite.com is the new site that I want to direct just the /blog pages too):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?eyewearconcierge\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/? https://www.thirdsite.com/eyestyle [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, now the blog redirect works perfectly but when I click links from the old site that are not /blog I get a 'Too many redirects' error in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I fixed this but I'd really like to be certain that I have done the right thing.

I discovered that changing the order of the two RewriteRule makes it work but I'm not sure why.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?eyewearconcierge\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/? https://www.thirdsite.com/eyestyle [R=301,L]
```